# Why does cx_Freeze make 32 bit executable when run on 64 bit Debian Linux?

Tags: linux, python-3.x, cx-freeze

I want to be able to make the executable in Linux. It works, except it is a 32 bit file. When I switch to Windows 10 and run the same setup.py file, it makes the 64 bit .exe. But, I want to do it in Linux since that is where my source code is written. I am using python 3.4

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you are running a 64-bit Python executable when you perform the freezing process and that this executable is the same one that you used to perform the installation of cx_Freeze in the first place. You can verify that you are running a 64-bit Python executable by running the following code in Python itself:

```
import struct
struct.calcsize("P")
```

This should return the value 8. You can also run the file command at the shell prompt as in

```
file `which python3.4`
```

This should return something like the following which will indicate if it is 64-bit or 32-bit.

/usr/bin/python3.4: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=9f7ffbe11edeecdab6596d4fa07cb559f788ac11, stripped